# Create CKAN resource in RoR, providing file content as string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, ckan

How does one create a CKAN resource in RoR, providing a string with file content?

This seems to be a working command line solution (if I save the file to filesystem):

```
curl -H 'Authorization: <api_key>' 'https://demo.ckan.org/api/action/resource_create' --form upload=@file.csv --form package_id=<pck_id>
```

Given that I have CSV file content as a string, how could I upload it to CKAN site?

Here is the code I have right now, resource is created but its content appears to be blank.

```
    http_client = HTTPClient.new

    temp_file = Tempfile.open('csv_export_tmp_file')
    temp_file.write(resource_content)

    body = {
      name: <filename>,
      title: <filetitle>,
      package_id: <package_id_here>,
      description: <description>,
      created: <created_at_time>,
      upload: temp_file,
      mimetype: 'text/csv',
      resource_type: 'file',
      format: 'csv'
    }
    response = http_client.post(resource_create_url, body, [['Authorization', api_key], ['Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data']])

    temp_file.close
    temp_file.unlink
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This it the solution that I ended up using

```
    resource_create_url = 'ckan_site_url.com/api/action/resource_create'

    http_client = HTTPClient.new

    extended_string_io = Class.new(StringIO) do
      def path
        'data.csv'
      end
    end

    virtual_file = extended_string_io.new("my, csv, file, content\n1,2,3,4")

    body = {
      name: <filename>,
      title: <filetitle>,
      package_id: <package_id_here>,
      description: <description>,
      created: <created_at_time>,
      upload: virtual_file,
      resource_type: 'file',
      format: 'csv'
    }
    response = http_client.post(resource_create_url, body, [['Authorization', api_key]])
```